# Rotated X Axis Labels Not Showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm having trouble making sure the D3 X labels are correctly included with the height of the entire SVG.

Given the following code, the X labels get rotated at a 45 degree angle but the area where the X labels are, D3 only shows half or none of the label.

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    gChart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
        .margin({ left: 65, right: 40 })
        .x(function(d) { return d.date })
        .y(function(d) { return d.total })
        .staggerLabels(false)
        .tooltips(true)
        .showValues(true);

    gChart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b %d, %Y')(new Date(d)) });

    gChart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('G');

    d3.select('#g-chart svg')
        .datum(formattedG)
        .transition()
        .duration(350)
        .call(gChart);

    d3.selectAll("#g-chart .nv-x .nv-axis text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + this.getBBox().height*-2 + "," + this.getBBox().height*2 + ")rotate(-45)";
        });

    updateGchart(formattedG);

    return gChart;
});
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that 'D3 only shows half or none of the label', the chances are high that the `text`'s position is beyond the svg canvas range, try to adjust the position by either adjusting the `translate` attribute or using other attributes such as [dx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dx), dy(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy), or `text-anchor` to adjust the text position.

Comment: looks like it was a simpler solution that i just found for nvd3 called "rotateLabels();"

Comment: cool, that's better, I didn't realize there is an api in nvd3 for this, but if it's just d3.js, dx dy text-anchor could be really helpful when adjusting text position.